# Implementing LONG background tasks on Azure webapps

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

Situation:

A user with a TB worth of files on our Azure blob storage and gigabytes of storage in our Azure databases decides to leave our services. At this point, we need to export all his data into 2GB packages and deposit them on the blob storage for a short period (two weeks or so).

This should happen very rarely, and we're trying to cut costs. Where would it be optimal to implement a task that over the course of a day or two downloads the corresponding user's blobs (240 KB files) and zips them into the packages?

I've looked at a separate webapp running a dedicated continuous webjob, but webjobs seem to shut down when the app unloads, and I need this to hibernate and not use resources when not up and running, so "Always on" is out. Plus, I can't seem to find a complete tutorial on how to implement the interface, so that I may cancel the running task and such.

Our last resort is abandoning webapps (three of them) and running it all on a virtual machine, but this comes up to greater costs. Is there a method I've missed that could get the job done?

Comment: Azure Web Apps are still web apps. They aren't suitable for long running jobs. You should loo at Azure Web Jobs or Azure Functions. Functions have the added advantage that they are charge only by actual usage, you don't need to purchase a specific size

Comment: actually you could easily implement a routine to create a web app, create web job and start it and delete the web app after that, but you would probably want to use azure functions for that...

Comment: Azure Functions really do look like the way to go. How would you go about handling the large file size with the 1.5GB memory limit on functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for a serverless model on Azure Functions to me.  You get the compute scale you need without paying for idle resources.

I don't believe that there are any time limits on running the function (unlike AWS Lambda), but even so you'll probably want to implement something to split the job up first so it can be processed in parallel (and to provide some resilience to failures).  Queue these tasks up and trigger the function off the queue.

It's worth noting that they're still in 'preview' at the moment though.

Edit - have just noticed your comment on file size... that might be a problem, but in theory you should be able to use local storage rather than doing it all in memory.

Comment: While most of this is true, the local storage is limited to 500MB. Is there a way to stream to blob storage?